# Pressing cancel on Google Sign In popup box locks any user interaction

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I've added a custom Google Login button for my app but as I was testing by pressing cancel on the popup screen I get `Error signing in:  Error Domain=com.google.GIDSignIn Code=-5 "The user canceled the sign-in flow."` error message and then my app doesn't respond anymore. I do have the following in my `AppDelegate.swift` file. I also call the sign in function through a button in my `LoginViewController`

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
import GooglePlaces

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("***********")
        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    }
```

LoginViewController

```
 @objc func googleLoginTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if NetworkReachabilityManager()!.isReachable {
            googleLoginView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
        } else {
            AlertBox.sendAlert(boxMessage: "Unable to connect to the internet. Please check connectivity before using app", presentingController: self)
        }
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let err = error {
            print("Error signing in: ", err)
            return
        }
```

So I know I have the URL call back but I do not know why my app keeps getting locked out.

Comment: googleLoginView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false.. remove this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point, you need to do this.

```
googleLoginView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: Heh...I forgot I added that in to make sure the user doesn't spam log in presses...